# Как превратить массив в двумерный

Tags: c++, c, массивы

Написал код по рандомному формированию массива. Теперь хочу что бы он стал двумерным. Что, где добавить?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <time.h>

#define max_value 30

void swap(double* p1, double* p2)
{
    double tmp = *p1;
    *p1 = * p2;
    *p2 = tmp;
}

void sort(double* vector, unsigned int size)
{
    signed short int swapping = 1;
    unsigned int j = 0;
    while(swapping > 0)
    {
        swapping = -1;
        for (j = 0; j < size - 1; ++j)
            if (vector[j] > vector[j + 1])
            {
                swap(vector + j, vector + j + 1);
                swapping = 1;
            }
    }
}

int main()
{
    unsigned int size, i = 0;
    double* vector;

    srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));

    printf("Enter the size of the vector\n");
    scanf("%d", &size);

    vector = (double*)malloc(sizeof(double) * size);

    if (vector == NULL)
    {
        perror("Out of memory");
        _getch();
        return 0;
    }

    printf("Vector:\n");
    for ( ; i < size; ++i)
        printf("%4.2lf ", vector[i] = rand() % max_value);

    sort(vector, size);

    printf("\nSorting array\n");
    for (i = 0 ; i < size; ++i)
        printf("%4.2lf ", vector[i]);

    system("pause");

    free(vector);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
unsigned int rows, cols;  // Размеры массива
double** vector;

...

vector = (double**)malloc(sizeof(double*) * rows);
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < cols; ++i)
    vector[i] = (double*)malloc(sizeof(double) * cols);

.....
// Работать как с обычным двумерным массивом - через vector[i][j]
.....

for(unsigned int i = 0; i < cols; ++i)
    free(vector[i]);
free(vector);
```

Только у вас просто C, никак не C++. В C++ `vector` - свой тип, не используйте там это имя, а то потом могут начаться неприятности. Кстати, с ним это выглядело бы так:

```
vector<vector<int>> arr(rows,vector<int>(cols));
```

И все - двумерный массив сформирован.

Comment: for ( ; i < rows; ++i)
  for ( ; j < cols; ++j){
        printf("%4.2lf ", &vector[i][j] = rand() % max_value);
  } Ошибка в принте "Error 2 error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'int' to 'double *' "

Comment: `&vector[i][j] = rand() % max_value` - что это за хреновину вы написали?!

Comment: А не проще ли  `array = malloc(rows * cols * sizeof(double)); for (i < rows) { vector[i]  = &array[i * cols * sizeof(double)]; }` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < sizeVert; ++i)
{
   for (int j = 0 ; j < sizeGoriz; ++j)
   {
        printf("%4.2lf ", vector[i][j] = rand() % max_value);
   }
}
```

Вроде так, если я верно понял вопрос